# How can I use Distinct on a specific property and select the object to keep based on a predicate?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List` of `Document` objects. The `Document` class has many properties but only two are relevant here, `DocumentLinkId` and `UploadedOnDate`.

What I want to do is filter the list down so there are no two `Document` objects with the same `DocumentLinkId`. When there is more than one `Document` object with a particular `DocumentLinkId` I want to keep the one with the latest `UploadedOnDate`.

My initial inclination was to do something like this:

```
myDocumentsList.Distinct(d => d.DocumentLinkId).Max(d => d.UploadedOnDate);
```

But `Distinct()` doesn't take a predicate. Is there a way to do this with LINQ?

Comment: Try grouping by `DocumentLinkId` and then taking the one in each group with the max `UploadedOnDate`

Comment: There is always an (old school) option of writing a for loop with a Dictionary<documentLinkId type, Date?> as a cache. It will probably work the fastest and be easier to debug if anything goes wrong, or you want to extend search criteria and the like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can group the documents by `DocumentLinkId`, and for each group, select the item with the latest `UploadedOnDate` like this:

```
var result = myDocumentsList
    .GroupBy(d => d.DocumentLinkId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.UploadedOnDate).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This throws an exception with the message `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.`

Comment: Are you using LINQ to Entities? Replace `First` with `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: In this case, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DistinctBy` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property).

> var query = people.DistinctBy(p => p.Id);

It will be something like:

```
myDocumentsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.UploadedOnDate).ToList().DistinctBy(d => d.DocumentLinkId).Max(d => d.UploadedOnDate);
```

for your case.

Comment: This will first select a set of documents with distinct `DocumentLinkId`. when it selects them it may or may not choose the ones with the most recent `UploadedOnDate`. Then, having created that set, it will select just the one document with the highest `UploadedOnDate`. So it doesn't return a distinct set. It returns one object.

Comment: You are right @ScottHannen I have updated my answer to select the entries in the list, first ordered by UploadedOnDate, and then to select them distinct by DocumentLinkId

Answer (score 1):

You can define an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Document>`. It exists for pretty much exactly this scenario.

```
public class DocumentLinkIdDocumentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Document>
{
    public bool Equals(Document document1, Document document2)
    {
        return document1.DocumentLinkId == document2.DocumentLinkId;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
myDocumentsList.OrderByDescending(d => d.UploadedOnDate)
    .Distinct(new DocumentLinkIdDocumentEqualityComparer())
```

(Had to edit this to order it first so that distinct returns the one with the most recent date.)

You're saying that for the purpose of this one `Distinct` comparison, let's use this comparer and act as if any two documents with the same `DocumentLinkId` are equal.

What's nice about that is that you don't have to modify `Document` to override `Equals`, especially since this particular equality comparison might not apply in every case. This lets you specify when you want to use a particular custom equality comparison.

Comment: I think it should be `return document1.DocumentLinkId == document2.DocumentLinkId;` Needs the ==

Comment: Yes, thanks. That's what happens when I code directly in the answer editor.